# How to access a different controller from inside a controller Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I need to access a method from a different controller inside another controller. How can I do it? Can I use `this->get` method?

Can I include the controller inside my current controller and make a object of it and access the method via the object? Is it "ok" to do it this way?

I want to call the form method --- newAction of the other controller.

Comment: I think you are not supposed to do that if you are following MVC, you should extract taht function into a Model or helper object.

Comment: Can you show how to do it the MVC way

Comment: What do you want with that controller?

Comment: as long as Symfony has things like "{{ render(controller(...)) }}"" MVC shouldn't be a concern

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can define your controller as service, then get it in another controller.

In your `services.yml` define needed controller as a service:

```
services:
    your_service_name:
        class: YourCompany\YourBundle\Controller\YourController
```

Then in any controller you'll be able to get this service via container:

```
$yourController = $this->get('your_service_name');
```

---

There is some useful information about [Controllers as Services](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/controller/service.html) in documentation

Comment: Is this the best way to do it. Or is there another way to do it

Comment: @CJ Well, as it was mentioned in comments, you shouldn't call controller action in another controller. But from Symfony2 POV - having controller defined as service is OK

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just wanted to make sure I am following the best parctice

Comment: I am getting this error **FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/cj/public_html/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 163.  The method which I am trying to call does exist. Can you help.  I have defined the service exactlty the way you told me

Comment: Services as controllers are not recommended, at least not by Febien - see: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/457

Comment: So the answer was accepted.  Did you get past the error message?  Did you read the cookbook entry and realize that it's up to you to inject additional services into you controller when defining it as a service?

Comment: How can you execute a method (which is not an Action and which is inside `YourController`) using the service? Thank you

Comment: @qooplmao  I have a subform/controller that needs to get presented on the same page... forwarding doesn't seem to be the answer. I just went with a static method and passed the context.

Comment: Another way could be to allow all your controllers to be used as Services. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342031/symfony2-use-doctrine-in-service-container/45269646#45269646). Also, if they aren't used, there is no performance cost!

Answer (score 73):

If you don't want to define the class as a service, as it doesn't feel as a good practice to me and @Qoop quoted [Fabien saying the same](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/457), you can use forwarding:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html

```
public function indexAction($name)
{
    $response = $this->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:fancy', array(
        'name'  => $name,
        'color' => 'green',
    ));

    // ... further modify the response or return it directly

    return $response;
}
```

If you need to embed the output of an internal controller-action in a template, the [documentation for Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html) also has something for that.

Comment: this is wrong as it will generate response using template of fancy action instead of template associated with indexAction

Comment: @gondo, you mean, if you use templates by annotations? Yepp. That's right. Then you'll get the generated template - so the response as it would've been sent back. If you want to get the data before annotations are used, then you have to define the class as service.

Comment: I see way bigger problems regarding the "forwarding" when it comes to unit testing. You won't be able to mock the subrequest, when you instead define your controller as a service, you can easily mock it.

Comment: @user3746259 If you want to write unit-tests for your controllers, I recommend reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126826/how-can-i-unit-test-a-symfony2-controller#10132372

Comment: I know how to write them (I recommended you do write some Unit Tests for the Controllers)  and thats why I said don't use the forwarding Option, or what do you mean?

Comment: @user3746259, please read the accepted answer. The answer is not about "how to", but more about how to test controllers. I agree with the author that unit-tests aren't the right tool for testing controllers. Functional-tests are.

Comment: Yep, and I said that I would unit test controllers a bit - for functional tests I'm using behat thats ok. There is no right answer if you should unit test parts of a controller or only do functional tests. I think it is important that you do functional tests (e.g. with behat) and in addition, you could do some unit tests. And when it comes to unit tests, you should not use the "forward" method because it generates a new request internally and you would need to mock a lot. Thats what I wanted to point out. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to instantiate the controller you want to access in the controller you are in.

The controller you are in:

*In symfony 2/3 you may have to put "YourBundle" instead of "App"

..

```
use App\Controller\DefaultController;
```

..

```
public function index()
{

    $default_controller = new DefaultController;
    $variable = 1;
    $default_controller->actionToCall($variable);

    return $this->render('...'); //The view you want to render or call another action
}
```

In the controller called:

```
public function actionToCall($variable)
{
    //dd($variable);        
}
```

Done.

Comment: Or use dependency injection if you need it to work for the whole class.