# Symfony2 call controller from another controller

Tags: symfony

I'm new to symfony2 and I've been trying to find the best way to call a controller from within another.

I have a list of events and I need an action to get all events and another action to get an event by ID but I don't want to keep repeating the doctrine calls each time I need to do this.

I thought about making a controller with all event actions and then calling the needed action from within other controllers each time I need it, if there is a better way to do it, I'm open for any suggestions.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827384/how-to-access-a-different-controller-from-inside-a-controller-symfony2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a piece of logic that should be reused, it probably doesn't belong in the controllers. You should try moving it to a service, which is easy to do.

In src/BundleName/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    service_name:
        class:        BundleName\Service\ServiceName
        arguments:    [@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager]
```

Then, create BundleName\Service\ServiceName class ([as shown in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)) with the logic to be reused. An example below:

```
class ServiceName {

    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct($entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function addProduct($product) {
        //Get the array, hydrate the entity and save it, at last.
        //...
        $entity = new Product();
        //...
        $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
        $this->entityManager->flush($entity);
        return $entity;

    }

}
```

Then, in your actions, just call `$this->get('service_name')->addProduct($array)`, or something like that.

Of course, if you want a controller action to be reused, [you can use your controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html). I'd advice you to add a service layer, though.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I think I'll do with services as you said. I'm not really bound to the controller embedding method, it was just the way I thought it should be done but yours sounds more convenient.