# How to access to a function of a controller from inside another controller in Symfony2?

Tags: function, symfony, controller

I would like to know how to access to a function of a controller from inside another controller in Symfony2. In fact I have two controllers: "EventgroupeController" and "GroupeController". In the code of the controller "EventgroupeController" I put the instruction below:

```
return GroupeController::AfficheGroupeAction();
```

But when I run the code (or let's say the project I am developing), it displays this error message in Symfony2:

ContextErrorException: Runtime Notice: Non-static method Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Controller\GroupeController::AfficheGroupeAction() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\wamp\www\Wkayet_project\PFESymfony2\src\Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Controller\EventgroupeController.php line 104

After having a look at this link: [How to access a different controller from inside a controller Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827384/how-to-access-a-different-controller-from-inside-a-controller-symfony2) in order to know how to access a different controller from inside a controller in Symfony2, I modified the content of the file services.yml as below:

```
 parameters:
#    ikproj_groupe.example.class: Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Example

services:
#    ikproj_groupe.example:
#        class: %ikproj_groupe.example.class%
#        arguments: [@service_id, "plain_value", %parameter%]
     controllerservice:
         class: Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Controller\GroupeController
```

Then, I replaced the instruction: `return GroupeController::AfficheGroupeAction();` by the lines below:

```
$yourController = $this->get('controllerservice');
$yourController1 = $yourController::AfficheGroupeAction();
return $yourController1;
```

But I still see this error message:

ContextErrorException: Runtime Notice: Non-static method Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Controller\GroupeController::AfficheGroupeAction() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\wamp\www\Wkayet_project\PFESymfony2\src\Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Controller\EventgroupeController.php line 106

So, my question is: how can I resolve this problem and how can I access to the function AfficheGroupeAction() of the controller "GroupeController" from inside the controller "EventgroupeController"?

Comment: Is this `AfficheGroupeAction` static method ?? Becouse the error says that its not.

Comment: No, it isn't a static method, by the way, this is the header of the function AfficheGroupeAction :
public function AfficheGroupeAction(){
Do you have any idea about how to call a non-static function??

Comment: Why You want to call it in another controller ?? If You need to do something whats inside this method move it to service, And call it in both places

Comment: Well I have to do that because after the validation of a form, a web page of a group will be displayed immediately..So for that reason I have to call a function of a controller inside another controller in Symfony2.

Comment: ok..it is done, please have a look at the answer at the bottom of the page

Comment: OMG. see instead `return GroupeController::AfficheGroupeAction();` use `forward` method `$this->forward('GrupeController:Aff...');`

Comment: @skowron-line: Well, I have to put "return" inside a controller in Symfony2, By the way I tried this instruction: return $this->forward('GroupeController::AfficheGroupeAction()'); but I obtained this error message: Class "GroupeController" does not exist. ... Then what is the correct instruction to put??

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding

Answer (score 0):

An action method must not be static.

```
$this->get('controllerservice')->youMethod();
```

Should work !

But with a good "application design", you should not have this need except if you want to forward a request from a controller to another ( example :  backward compatibility ). In this case you can use the **forward** method  provided by symfony2 base controller. ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html )

Comment: Well, I tried this code: return $this->get('controllerservice')->AfficheGroupeAction(); but I obtained this error message: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Wkayet_project\PFESymfony2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 256 ... So as you can notice here, it didn't work!!...By the way, what is the problem here?

Comment: Your controller extends Symfony2 Controller class?

Comment: yes of course it does, this is its header: class GroupeController extends Controller

Comment: would like that I give you all the code of the controller??

Comment: If you want to get help give maximum info :)

Comment: ok, I will put all the code of each of the controller "EventgroupeController" , the controller "GroupeController" and the file services.yml in an answer at the bottom.

Comment: ok...it is done, please have a look at the answer at the bottom of the page.