# I want to call a function from one controller to another controller

Tags: php, symfony

i have

```
class examController{
     public function regMail(){

     }
}
```

i want to call regMail() in authController

```
class authController{
    // i want regMail() here

}
```

Comment: Controllers should contain actions. Sending mails looks like a job for a service. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: put your action in modal instead and then call it from controller

Comment: You should look at the documentation and try to understand how to use services and what is the service container provided by Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

To doing that, you have 2 solutions :

1 -  Use [forwarding](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller) (the good practice) ;

```
    //In your controllor
    public function indexAction($name) {

      $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:Something:fancy', array(
          'name'  => $name,
          'color' => 'green',
      ));

      // ... further modify the response or return it directly

      return $response;
     }
```

2 -  Define your controller as service (the bad practice) ;

Try to look a this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827384/how-to-access-a-different-controller-from-inside-a-controller-symfony2) for more details and (of course) the official documentation.
Good luck ^^!