# PHP - Symfony: How do i make a new object inside a class that's from another class?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, model-view-controller, symfony-2.8

I made a PHP Symfony project for learning purposes. Now i am stuck, so i have a Controller, which renders a View. But inside that Controller i want to access another Controller and make an object, because i need it's method.

So in short: How can i make a class/object inside another class in Symfony?

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Controller\LoginController;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function renderIndexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('username', TextType::class, array('label' => 'username:'))
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array('label' => 'password:'))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'login'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user = $form->getData();
            $user_username = $user->getUsername();
            $user_password = $user->getPassword();

            $loginController = new LoginController();
            $user = $loginController->checkAction();


            $session = $request->getSession();
            $data = "test";
            $session->set('form_data', $data);


            return $this->redirectToRoute('addressbook');
        }

        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

So i want to use the LoginController inside my HomeController. But it gives me an error:

Call to a member function has() on null
500 Internal Server Error - FatalThrowableError

PS: Yes i know that my app is not safe, but i am still learning basic OOP. So it might be a weird way to call a LoginController like that. But it's for learning purposes.

Comment: What method do you need from there? Add it's code here. You might want to extract it into separate service and inject into both controllers instead of trying to create a Controller within another controller.

Comment: If you want to access another endpoint of another controller, look up sub-requests. If you want to re-use another controller's method, make that method into a service and inject use that service in both controllers.

Comment: You don't want to use another controller's instance in your controller, that's wrong logic; You should read about MVC principle.

In your case you probably want to create another class - a service class, and both controllers will use that service.

You should also read about dependency injection, for loading the service class.

Comment: Why is it wrong to make a Controller inside another Controller? All i wanted is to make an object from a class inside another class?

Comment: I am trying to make a service from that Controller. Is it enough to write this in services.yml:

services:
    app.login_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\LoginController

And can i call the LoginController like this: $loginController = app.login_controller; 

?

Comment: NVM, it works now. I am using a service now. This link explains it: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your issue actually stems from the fact, that you are using the controllers wrong. You have managed push the *application logic* in them, which is causing your current problem.

Instead of creating `User` instance and doing the authentication in a controller, all of that should be handled by services (like `Authentication` service). If a controller needs access to a service, said service should be passed as a dependency to that controller.

This would also give you a natural way for sharing logic between multiple controllers, because multiple controller then can depend on same services.

**Update**

So, the `services.yml` file would look kinda like this:

```
services:

    controller.auth:
        class: 'Application\Controller\Authentication'
        arguments: ['@service.recognition', '@service.comunity']

    controller.account:
        class: 'Application\Controller\Authentication'
        arguments: ['@service.comunity']

    service.recognition:
        class: 'Model\Service\Recognition'

    service.community:
        class: 'Model\Service\Community'
```

In this case the `Community` service is shared between two unrelated controllers.

> <sub>**P.S.** you might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) useful</sub>

Comment: Why is it wrong to make a Controller inside another Controller? All i wanted is to make an object from a class inside another class?

Comment: I am trying to make a service from that Controller. Is it enough to write this in services.yml:

services:
    app.login_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\LoginController

And can i call the LoginController like this: $loginController = app.login_controller; 

?

Comment: NVM, it works now. I am using a service now. This link explains it: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container.html

Comment: @alandibat updated to show an example. And please, do not call the DI container from within a controller class.

Comment: @alandibat as for "why it is bad idea", there are couple reasons. First of all, it cause a tight coupling between controller (which should be the most lightweight part of an application). It also means, that your controller now has additional responsibility - to "re-execute in a separate context". Aaaand, you would also end up with some "controllers" without consistent methods (as in, in Sf2.x you usually return a `Response` instance from all public methods).

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can use a controller from another controller is to define a controller as a service and then use it.

take a look at this answer [how-to-access-a-different-controller-from-inside-a-controller-symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827384/how-to-access-a-different-controller-from-inside-a-controller-symfony2)

here is official doc [Define Controllers as Services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html)

Comment: If you need to call one controller from another, then you have made an architectural mistake.

Comment: @tereško I agree, just for accuracy if you detect that the request should be handled by another controller, in this case you might forward the request to another controller. It's a specific case don't worry about this, just to know that it exist

Comment: Why is it wrong to make a Controller inside another Controller? All i wanted is to make an object from a class inside another class?

Comment: I am trying to make a service from that Controller. Is it enough to write this in services.yml:

services:
    app.login_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\LoginController

And can i call the LoginController like this: $loginController = app.login_controller; 

?

Comment: NVM, it works now. I am using a service now. This link explains it: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container.html

Comment: Move your code into a service is the good way. Service are very very powerfull. If some code may be reusable into another context, you should directly think about a service :)